# kendoui grid filter panel customization - css

Tags: css, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I can't understand how to fix this (strange) behaviour about kendoui gird filter:

This is my grid (where the filter panel takes all the page)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5v3R.jpg

Instead in the official example il takes the right space
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWny5.jpg

How you can see exploring the code, the panel dimensions have been applyed  by inline styles, probably in my code there is something that "pollute" the normal style

- how can i investigate more?
- how can i give you more details about it?
- who and where are applied these inline styles to set the dimensions?
- is it possible to fix it overwriting in some way?
- any suggestion?

--UPDATED--
to replicate my situation do the followng:

1) download this file here : http://www.filedropper.com/panelfilterdimensionsproblem and unzip it (i've replicated my enviroment, the layout is broken but isn't so important).

2) open index.html with Chrome and double click on the "InterCompany Attive" item.

3) click on the grid's "funnel" (the first, the upper funnel, that one that opens the filter panel).

4) how  you can see the filter panel takes the whole screen (wrong behaviour) instead of getting only needed dimensions.

5) i'm sure that my custom css (mystyle.css) have "polluted" some kendoui style (take a look at the second funnel inside the button, isn't centered. I soppose that is coused by the same css problem).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5W9m.jpg

Comment: can you post your html/css ?

Comment: i updated the original post with code attached